# Referencing Excel from Visio error 'library not registered'

Tags: vba, excel, visio

I'm trying to move information from Visio to Excel.  My standard code for using excel is giving a:
'run time error- 2147319779 (8002801d):
automation error
library not registered'

I have checked 'Microsoft Excel 15 Object Library' is checked in references

My code is throwing an error on the createobject line below:

```
Sub BreakStringInExcel()
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSh As Excel.Worksheet

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

'Error on the above line
    Set xlWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\tom\Desktop\Workbook1.xlsx")
    Set xlSh = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet Name")
    .....

```
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlSh = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?  the code runs fine from excel

Comment: For which line does the run time error occur? I guess `Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` ?

Comment: Also what version of Visio are you using?

Comment: Correct, the line starting set xlApp...
Visio Professional 2016 32-bit

Comment: And is the Excel install 32-bit as well?

Comment: Yep, Excel 2013 32bit

Comment: Did you try `Set xlApp = New Excel.Application` instead of `Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` ? I ask because normally the `CreateObject` method is used with late binding but you already referenced the correct library (i.e. you are using early binding). Don't know if this will solve, but maybe Visio is particularly finicky.

Comment: I get the same error message both ways.  I actually switched to the late binding after the Set xlApp = New Excel.Application failed, but as i say im still getting the same error message in both scenarios

Comment: Hmm.. smells like dependencies. Do you also have references for `OLE Automation` and `Microsoft **Office** 15.0 Object Library` ?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft Office 16 Object Library and OLE Automation

Comment: Also, when you used late binding did you declare your variables as `Object` and not `Excel.Whatnot`? Sorry.. clutching at straws a little bit...

Comment: Nope, honestly I'm not that hot on the difference between the two methods.  All i changed was the line thats giving the error, the dimensions were the same.
I just tried 
dim xlApp as object
Set xlApp = CreateObject(Excel.Application)
but to no avail

Comment: Is Office 365 installed?  In my experience the 365 installer hoses the references, so you have to late bind without any Excel reference to get Visio to work with Excel 365.